# Refused to execute a script because its hash or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

Refused to execute a script because its hash or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

This is happening with Google Ads. My Nginx has:
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";

What do I add/change to fix that error so my google ads show?

Answer (score 0):

There are likely multiple CSPs active, and all content needs to pass all policies. Check the response headers and meta tags for other CSPs and modify/remove them to have a single CSP.

Comment: The response says Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' 'unsafe-inline'

Comment: I don't think 'unsafe-inline' makes sense in a frame-ancestors source list. You probably want something like "frame-ancestors 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' <additional sources>". The console log will tell you which host names are necessary to load all the ads.